# how to filter events based on a id from another table on fullcalendar js laravel 8

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, laravel-8

This is my first time with fullcalendar and I want to filter employee's vacation according to their department
Thank you very much for your help

```
<div class="card-body">
<a href="{{url('conges/create')}}"  class="btn btn-success pull-right">Ajouter un congé</a>
    <form action="{{ url('conges')}}" method="GET">
        Services:
            <select name="select_service" id="select_service">
                <option value=""> all services</option>
                @foreach($services as $service)
                <option value="{{$service->id}}"
                @if (request('select_service') == $service->id) selected @endif>{{$service->nom_serv}} </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Filtrer</button>
    </form>

<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto my-4">
    <div id="fcalendar"></div>
</div>
```

How can I display events according to service_id
when I click on submit button Filtrer

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // Test Fullcalendar
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('fcalendar')
    
    let id_service = document.querySelector("#select_service");
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['bootstrap', 'dayGrid','interaction'],
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        header :     {
                left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today', 
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay' 
                },
        //events : '/callendrier',
        events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                        var id_service = $('#select_service').val();
                        console.log(id_service)
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"GET",
                            url:"{{url('/callendrier')}}"+ (id_service != "" ? '/' + id_service : ""),
                        }).done(function(data) {
                            successCallback(data); //use the supplied callback function to return the event data to fullCalendar
                        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                            failureCallback(jqXHR);
                        });
                },
 calendar.render();
    $('#select_service').change(function() {
                calendar.refetchEvents();
                //console.log(id_service)
                });
```

this is my congecontroller,maybe i dont know how to send the correct data

```
 public function index()
{
    $listemps = Employe::all();
    $listype=Typeconge::all();
    $services= Service::all();
    //$conges=Conge::all();
    return view('conge.index')->with([
            'employes'=>$listemps,
            'typeconges'=>$listype,
            'services'=>$services
]);
   
}
public function callendrier()
{
    return $this->eventsToArray(Conge::all());
}
public function eventsToArray($conges)
{
    $eventArray = [];
    foreach($conges as $conge){
        $data = [ 
            'id' =>$conge->id,
            "title" => $conge->employe->nom_emp,
            "type" =>$conge->typeconge->type,
            "dure_conge" => $conge->dure_conge,
            "start" => $conge->start_date,
            "end" => $conge->end_date  ,
            "remplacant" => $conge->remplacant, 
            "solde_conge" => $conge->solde_conge, 
            "color"=>$conge->color,
            "employes"=>$conge->employe_id,
            "services"=>$conge->employe->poste->serv_id,
            "textColor" => "white"
        ];
        array_push($eventArray,$data);
    }
    return response()->json($eventArray); 
}
```

Comment: You didn't really explain what problem you're having. Your code looks like it should work, basically. Please clarify the exact issue, and what you've done so far to try and resolve it. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is when i select service(departement) it should show only the vacation employees that belong to that service, but i dont know how .Thanks

Comment: Ok. But where exactly are you stuck with that? The code you've shown us seems to already implement all the steps it would need to do - when the dropdown selection changes, it refetches the events, which runs the callback function, gets the selected ID from the dropdown, and sends it to the server. Then, when the response comes back from the server, it updates the calendar with the new set of events. So what is the problem? Does what you've shown all function as expected, the way I've just described?

Comment: Are you perhaps having a problem with how to write the code on the server to filter the list and return the correct data? We don't know, because you haven't shown any server-side code, and all you've done is state your requirement tell us you don't know how to implement it, when in fact you've done quite a few of the necessary steps already. You need to be much more specific about where you're having a problem, and make sure you've shown us all the relevant code, so that we can help you properly.

Comment: thank you @ADyson for trying to help i really appreciate that , i just added my congecontroller ,as you told maybe i dont know how to send data .

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a Laravel user, but it seems you need to alter your callendrier() function so it accepts the service ID as input from the request, and then replace conge:all() with a query (probably using where()) which gets only items from the database which have the ID in the relevant column in the database table. That's fairly standard stuff and I'm quite sure online you can find examples of those things in Laravel tutorials, documentation etc.